# Getting deleted users in database

Tags: database, sql

I am using the database that is being used by a WordPress site.

I am trying to get all the users from `wp_users` table with SQL query. But there is also previously deleted users in `wp_users` table. I searched other tables like `wp_usermeta` but I couldn't find any status or column which identifies if that user deleted or not.

Are there any table or column where WordPress website stores information about deleted users?

Comment: when we delete user from wordpress then it will completely removed from database and its value from meta table also deleted. So how can you get previously deleted user.

Comment: Are you saying that there are deleted users whose information remains in the DB?  Is this a Multisite install? (On Multisite, when you "delete" a user from a site, you really only remove her from that site; she's still a user, and can still be added back to that site, or to others.)